# Ionic3 + Firebase Database security + PayPal

Tags: firebase, paypal, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, firebase-security

I'm using Ionic 3 with Firebase Database and PayPal for payments. In my App users are able to purchase via PayPal listings offered by other users on the App (marketplace). I ran into problems with the correct Firebase Database rules I need to implement for my database.

On the one hand, when a given listing is purchased, the buyer needs to update the status of the listing to SOLD (so that no one else buys it again). On the other hand, on the owner of the listing should be authorized to edit his/her listing. There are the rules I have right now, which don't really solve my dilemma.

```
    "explore": {
      ".read": "auth.provider === 'facebook'",
      "$listing": {
        ".write": "auth.provider === 'facebook' && ((!data.exists() && newData.exists()) || root.child('explore/'+$listing+'/UID').val() === auth.uid)",
      }
    },
```

Maybe there is a way to do it from the backend of Firebase Functions? Any advice on how to go about solving this problem will be greatly appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your current rules? I.e. what action (code preferred) is being allowed that should not be (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Cloud Function that performs the payment processing and marks the listing as sold if the payment is successful. For example, you could create an `onCreate` event listener for `user-purchases/{uid}/{listing}` which when triggered would attempt payment.

If the payment is a success, write the transaction ID back to `user-purchases/{uid}/{listing}` along with any other purchase specific information, and using `firebase-admin` set the status of the listing as sold, and perform any other consequential actions.

Otherwise, if the payment fails, write the error message returned by PayPal.

Comment: How can I call the PayPal plugin from the backend? I'm using Native Plugin http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/. Is there a way the user/buyer can call PayPal from the frontend and then pass the returned object to the Cloud Function for further processing and writing to the Database as an Admin?